# Kotlin Lists and Arrays

Tags: kotlin

Just started working with Kotlin and I love it but...
I can not make any sense of Lists and Arrys in this language.
I'm not new to programming and do not need an explanation on what arrays are. What I do not understand is.

1. What is the difference between a List and an Array? They seem very much the same you access both using a[index] and use them in much the same way. If a list is immutable they are even more the same, so... What is the difference? Assuming the list is not a linked list they both work in O(1) access time.
2. If I'm using a list; What is the difference between mutable and immutable? When can I edit the content? When can I change the length?
3. There seem to be many overlapping and confusing names for the same thing. List, ListOf, ArrayList, IntArray, intArray....
   Could someone make an exhaustive list of all of them and give some kind of rule of thumb when you would use every one. Specifically, I find the concept of an immutable empty list very perplexing. What on earth would that be used for?
4. How do you initialize these things?

Sorry for the long question,

Thanks.

Comment: You are correct but I looked at the answers there and came out the other end as confused as I went in.

Comment: It answers precisely the questions you have including references to further reading. How would you expect a "better" answer to look like?

Comment: Coming from C/C++ the multitude of different names is very confusing. The technicality of the implementation behind the scenes (implementing an interface vs being a proper object etc..., will be interesting to me once I understand the logic/point of the different entities their **naming**).

After reading the documentation and the above-referenced answer, I still wouldn't know how to init an array/list or when would be the appropriate place to use an ArrayList vs List<Int> vs IntArray vs intArray.....

I think what I need is the big picture if this is irrelevant, please delete the Q.

Answer (score 6):

1. First difference is that `List` is interface describing some common list operations, while `Array` is a class. From memory perspective, `Array` is continuous region in memory which size doesn't change, that is why you can't change the size of `Array` after it is created, but you can change its elements, on other hand `List` can be implemented in different ways, meaning that memory structure can be different, most common implementations are `ArrayList` where array is used to store elements, and once array is filled, its changed with bigger array with contents of old one being added to new one, another implementation is `LinkedList`, where you have nodes pointing to next element on list. From performance perspective `Array` is always faster than any implementation of `List` but it is also much more limited.
2. Difference between `List` and `MutableList` is that when you use `MutableList` you can change elements of that list(add or remove elements from it), while when using immutable `List` you can't add or remove elements from it. Both lists allow you to change properties of those elements.
3. Will divide this answer into three answers:

   - `List` is the interface which extends `Collection` interface, provides basic common list operations, `MutableList` extends `List` interface as well as `MutableCollection` interface adding methods needed to change elements of that list, `listOf` is function which creates `List` and fills it with given arguments, by using `listOf` we don't need to specify which implementation of `List` will be used, for example on JVM `List` is backed by `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`(not same as `java.util.ArrayList`), while on JavaScript side it is probably backed up by `Array`(take this statement with grain of salt, as I have never worked with Kotlin for JS)
   - `ArrayList` is **typealias** to `java.util.ArrayList`, there is nothing special about it, it is implemenentation of Java's `List` interface, `MutableList` is backed by this implementation on JVM.
   - `Array` is equivalent to Java's array, nothing special for it either, `IntArray` and other primitive array company is used to make up for the lack of primitive types in kotlin, `Array<Int>` is same as `Integer[]` in Java, while `IntArray` is same as `int[]`. Same logic is applied to all other variants. Using primitive types you get better performance, but difference can be neglected in most cases on modern computers, still if you have really a lot of data you should go for primitive types where possible.

You can see yourself all collections hierarchy on [kotlin repository](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Collections.kt)

4. Use built-in Kotlin functions like `listOf`, `arrayOf`, `mutableListOf`, this isn't a must, but its always good to follow best practices.

Comment: Thanks, this was a help

Comment: Would it be correct to say. If it is preformance critical use an array, otherwise use a list. If using a list try to init it using `listOf` `mutableListOf` and let the compiler deside what kind of list to create. So creating a mutable ist of 100 cells init to 0 would look like `val l2 = mutableListOf((1..100).map{0})`

Comment: ment `val l2 = (1..100).map{0}.toMutableList()`

Comment: Yes array is better for performance critical tasks, otherwise lists are preferred as they offer a lot more flexibility. For initializing lists yes using those factory functions is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

> Coming from C/C++ the multitude of different names is very confusing.

Then maybe this can give C++ analogy specifically:

1. `Array` is like `std::array` (though length doesn't need to be known at compile time), or like C arrays, except it stores the length and all accesses are bounds-checked.
2. `ArrayList` is like `std::vector` (again, all accesses are bounds-checked).
3. `MutableList` is the interface to `ArrayList` (like [`SequenceContainer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/SequenceContainer)).
4. `List` is the read-only part of `MutableList`.

Generics work very differently from C++ templates, in particular there's no specialization: in C++, there is separate code generated for `std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<std::string>`, in Java and Kotlin there isn't. (Actually, Kotlin has a form of it with reified type parameters, but it doesn't apply here.) So e.g. `Array<Int>` and `List<Int>` have to work with boxed `java.lang.Integer`s instead of primitive types. But Java does have arrays of primitives, and that's what Kotlin calls `IntArray`.

Comment: Thanks.
Every one really helped me a lot